# rBoard installation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After unzipping the `rBoard`, and running `rake gems:install`, I get the following **error**:

> C:\Communit\rboard>rake gems:install --trace (in C:/Communit/rboard)
>   DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/acts_as_snook/tasks
>   are deprecated. Use  lib/tasks instead. (called from
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/
>   tasks/rails.rb:10)
>   ** Invoke gems:install (first_time)
>   ** Invoke gems:base (first_time)
>   ** Execute gems:base
>   ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>   ** Execute environment
>   **rake aborted! uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin** C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependenci
>   es.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependenci
>   es.rb:80:in`const_missing'
>   C:/Communit/rboard/config/environment.rb:86
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in
>   `gem_original_re quire'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in`
>   require'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependenci
>   es.rb:156:in `require'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependenci
>   es.rb:521:in`new_constants_in'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependenci
>   es.rb:156:in `require'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in`
>   call'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in
>   `execute'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in`
>   each'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in
>   `execute'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in`
>   invoke_with_call_c hain'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in`
>   invoke_with_call_c hain'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in
>   `invoke'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/tasks/gems.rake:17
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in`
>   call'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in
>   `execute'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in`
>   each'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in
>   `execute'
>   C:/Tools/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in`
>   invoke_with_call_c

Any idea what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Sass::Plugin is provided by the Haml gem. Install this gem and try the rake task again.